# How to make a stopwatch pause when user clicks on the same button twice with vanilla JS?

Tags: javascript

I am currently learning JS and trying to build a simple stopwatch for practice. It has 2 buttons - RESET and START:

[image]

HTML:

```
<section class="stopwatch">
  <div class="numbers">00:00:00</div>
  <ul class="buttons">
    <li>
      <button class="btn reset">RESET</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button class="btn btn-start start">START</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

What I am trying to do is when user clicks the "START" button the stopwatch starts and the button becomes "STOP". Then when clicked again the stopwatch stops or pauses to its current position and the button again becomes "START" and so on.

What I am struggling with is the second click to pause the stopwatch.

This is what I got so far:

```
let seconds = '00';
let minutes = '00';
let hours = '00';
let startStopwatch;

function startTimer() {
  seconds = Number(seconds) + 1;
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  } else if (seconds === 60) {
    seconds = '00';
    minutes = Number(minutes) + 1;
  }

  if (typeof minutes === 'number' && Number(minutes) < 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (Number(minutes) === 60) {
    minutes = '00';
    hours = Number(hours) + 1;
  }

  if (typeof hours === 'number' && Number(hours) < 10) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }

  document.querySelector(
    '.numbers'
  ).textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', function () {
  startStopwatch = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
  document.querySelector('.start').textContent = 'STOP';
});

document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(startStopwatch);
  seconds = '00';
  minutes = '00';
  hours = '00';
  document.querySelector(
    '.numbers'
  ).textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use flag variable. The bStart variable of bool type is used. It will work for you well. Also when the reset button is clicked, the "STOP" text should be changed into "START".

```
let seconds = '00';
let minutes = '00';
let hours = '00';
let startStopwatch;
let bStart = false;
function startTimer() {
  seconds = Number(seconds) + 1;
  if (seconds < 10) {
    seconds = '0' + seconds;
  } else if (seconds === 60) {
    seconds = '00';
    minutes = Number(minutes) + 1;
  }

  if (typeof minutes === 'number' && Number(minutes) < 10) {
    minutes = '0' + minutes;
  }

  if (Number(minutes) === 60) {
    minutes = '00';
    hours = Number(hours) + 1;
  }

  if (typeof hours === 'number' && Number(hours) < 10) {
    hours = '0' + hours;
  }

  document.querySelector(
    '.numbers'
  ).textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
}

document.querySelector('.start').addEventListener('click', function () {
  if(!bStart) {
    bStart = true;
    startStopwatch = setInterval(startTimer, 1000);
    document.querySelector('.start').textContent = 'STOP';
  } else {
    bStart = false;
    clearInterval(startStopwatch);
    document.querySelector('.start').textContent = 'START';
  }
});

document.querySelector('.reset').addEventListener('click', function () {
  clearInterval(startStopwatch);
  seconds = '00';
  minutes = '00';
  hours = '00';
  document.querySelector(
    '.numbers'
  ).textContent = `${hours}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
  document.querySelector('.start').textContent = 'START';
  bStart = false;
});
```